# Checking a file's content type by URL?

Tags: c#, mime-types, content-type, httpwebresponse

I am working on an app that downloads various kinds of media from different places- a lot of them user entered.  I'm discovering that a lot of the content-types found in the http response are garbage.  Mostly for videos it seems.  So an example would be a .wmv file somewhere on the web, but when I go grab it it says its content type is text/plain.

Is there some way to check file types besides this response content-type?  I was reading a bit about magic numbers for files, but I'm not sure how reliable that is... maybe it's more reliable than the response content-type?

Suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fool proof way is to actually try and open the file (with your application) and see if it gets parsed correctly.

However, if you want an API that you can use that will try and determine what the proper MIME type is from given data you can use [FindMimeFromData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  While this is a native Win32 function, you can still use it through [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata).

Comment: Very nice... I think this requires that I download the data first though, right?  In a perfect world, I would have my url, check the content type through some web service and then store as the correct type.  As opposed to storing as the wrong type then fixing.  Maybe I'll set up my own service to do this :)

Comment: You don't have to download the whole file. For example, you can typically identify a video from the first few kilobytes. There are files that can fool you, but they're unusual. My experience has been that if the content type says it's something other than a video, then it probably isn't. I ignore those. If the content type says that it *is* something that I'm interested in, I download the first few kilobytes, do a quick check of the file format, and if that passes then I'll consider downloading the whole thing.

Comment: @Jim Mischel that sounds like exactly what I would like to do.  Any example code to make my life easier?  :) Cheers.

Comment: @Nicros: Downloading just part of the file is pretty easy. Just make the request and then read only as many bites as you need. Determining if the data is the right format is rather more involved. I don't have any code I can share. You'll have to track down code that identifies the different video types.